# Efective method to find last row vba excel

Tags: vba

i have the following method to set to define a ranga:

```
Set RegJan = Sheets("BD").Range("T3:T50000")
```

the range is smaller than this, but in order to make it work for some months, i set it to 50000 rows.

i then use this code in the following line of vba:

```
ws.Cells(8, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(RegJan, 
EquipaBd, EquipaForm, AgenteBd, AgenteForm) 'Soma dos Registos
```

This last line i already transformed in a loop so that it calculates in every line i need it,the problem is that i have to do the first line of code  for every month of the year an for 6 more variables

is there a better way of doing this? possibly a dynamic way?

Comment: `set r=Sheets("BD").Range("T3").resize(Sheets("BD").Range("T3:T50000").end(xlUp).row,1)`

Comment: There is a growing consensus that this is a duplicate of a question about finding the last used row in a column. Is that what your question is about? If not, you'll have to clarify. Maybe [edit] your post and include some more code.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas:

```
With Sheets("BD")

    ' Since T is column #20 and goes to 6 more
    For col = 20 To 26

        ' get last row
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

        ' set range
        Set yourRng = .Range(.Cells(3, col), .Cells(lastRow, col))

        ' you might want to change 8,2 to make dynamic
        ws.Cells(8, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(yourRng , EquipaBd, EquipaForm, AgenteBd, AgenteForm)

    Next
End With
```